# how image is stored in a byte array

Tags: .net, image, arrays, ascii

How is an image internally stored in a byte array? While debugging in Visual Studio, I can see ASCII codes(I guess). But please someone explain it.

Say, we have an image(BLOB) stored in a table. Fetching that BLOB into a dataTable in the code(in .net) as,

```
byte[] image = new image();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(byte[]));
\\Consider the BLOB from the DB is fetched into DataTable Image column.
image = dt[Row]["Image"];
```

Now, how is the BLOB internally stored in byte[] image?

I've searched in the internet but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Where does this byte array reside?  Is it memory-resident or on-disk?  Does the image format support transparency?  More information is needed to answer this question.

Comment: @ManikandanSigamani are you wondering what format it is?

Comment: I guess I don't understand where your confusion is coming from.  On a computer, pretty much everything is stored in bytes - whether on the disk, on a CD, or a DVD, or in memory.  A byte array is just a collection of bytes.  Theoretically, the contents of the byte array would be the same as what you'd see if you used a HEX editor to view the bytes of the corresponding image as saved on the disk.  Perhaps this article will help you to conceptualize how it works.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93081/ASP-NET-Generating-Images-on-the-Fly

Comment: @DavidStratton Thanks for the link, I was actually breaking my head over another issue, where I've one mad at. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any image is merely a sequence of bytes structured in accordance with whatever underlying format used to represent it, eg color data, layers, dimensions, etc. The significance of any byte(s) you see during debugging is entirely dependent upon the native format of the image, eg PNG, TIFF, JPEG, BMP, etc.

Hope that's what you were looking for. If you're needing something more specific, please amend your original post and perhaps someone can give you more detail.

Comment: +1 - right, without the format the bytes are useless.  the native format has an algorithm for how it's laid out in bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is not clear for you but maybe this code can help

```
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();

Image img = Image.FromFile(file);
img.Save(m, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

byte[] bytes = m.ToArray();

m.Position = 0;
Image img2 = Image.FromStream(m);
```

Comment: I was wondering why a dataTable's column cannot be of type OracleLOB, and suddenly, I went mad. Thanks for the code, that helped better.

Comment: +1 : @Manikandan - the key bit here is ImageFormat.Jpeg.  Without the image format, bytes are just bytes.  Similar with strings - without the encoding, it's just bytes and you can't make sense out of it.  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @bryanmac the link sounds very interesting, I'm ashamed that I don't have an idea of it yet. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

An image is usually an array of colors encoded by a certain algorithm in a file. I am familiar with GIF image format. Look at the picture below to see an example where a red colored "V" is stored in a white colored background. The image width in this example could be 7 pixels and height would be 4 pixels. Every image always has a color table indicating the number of colors used in the image. The R marked pixels are the red ones and the w marked pixels are white colored.

```
RwwwwwR
wRwwwRw
wwRwRww
wwwRwww
```

Each pixel is an integer 32 bit wide to tell the r(red)g(green)b(blue) components and a transparency component.